# Bluetooth in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, bluetooth, meteor

I'm pretty new to Meteor and web development and such.

My essential question is: is there a 'right' way to communicate with a client's Bluetooth hardware in Meteor/js?

Currently, I'm thinking of writing a driver that takes the Bluetooth data and sends it in a stream to localhost, but that seems a little bit roundabout.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to go via an `npm` module in Meteor. For this you need to make a package that uses something like `bluetooth-serial-port` to allow Meteor to communicate with the device using the host device's bluetooth serial port (https://npmjs.org/package/bluetooth-serial-port) (You will need the bluetooth development headers too)

Avital has made a package demonstrating how to use npm modules with meteor : https://github.com/avital/meteor-xml2js-npm-demo